# Alternative to Check Boxes on Mobile

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, touch-screen, multi-selection

What other options are there for a more usable intuitive multi-select on mobile?

[image]

Comment: Can we get more details here? Is this for one-off buttons? Lists of selections? What is the use-case you have in mind here?

Comment: Interesting question but as JonW said we need a few more details.

Comment: Would be a list of selections like the image above. It's a responsive web app.

Comment: I was just curious if there was any common or new innovative ways to do multi-select. I'm new to StackExchange so thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: Check boxes aren't dead, you just need to give them a bigger tap area. I tend to use a custom control in these cases that is self-evident as a "big check box".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have (apologies as this is crude):

**Switches:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdOmEV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

or

**Suggest 'Hit Area' around the item:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXlf08.png)</sup>

Comment: @SteveJones First of all be sure to a 3min read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465475.aspx  . Microsoft has some great insights, didn't expect that :). 
Now considering the nature of touching a screen, the hit area is just better in most cases because it can provide a large tapping area and it lets you keep the "select box" UI element.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have a touch interface and you are willing to explore options, I think circling items would be a pretty interesting way to do multi-selection. This probably wouldn't work so well on a mobile phone, but perhaps a tablet would be an ideal way to explore how this might work.

Comment: Does this mean displaying a circle to show that the item is selected, or making the user draw a circle to select an item? The latter would be a huge pain for users with mobility impairments / motor issues, those in a rush, and those trying to work one-handed.

Comment: @octern Point taken, although the question is pretty generic and doesn't really specify such requirements (and I know we should be doing inclusive design). As an alternate approach circling would be interesting to implement though. I think the mobile interface is not designed to handle too much interactions, despite all the gesturing APIs being developed and used in at least the gaming apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool bootstrap library for mobile-friendly switches (checkbox alternatives)

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html